# Ways to organize Settings in Sublime Text plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Perhaps it is another round of "static vs instance" but I am trying to be devil in details.
Note that I am fairly new to Python and plugin development.

Some plugins use the following code:

```
s = sublime.load_settings(__name__ + '.sublime-settings')

class Settings:
  def load(self):
    self.setting1 = s.get('setting1', 'default1')
    self.setting2 = s.get('setting2', 'default2')
    ...

# Global Scope

settings = Settings()
settings.load()
s.add_on_change(__name__ + '-reload', settings.load)
```

There is nothing particularly wrong with this example except `load_settings` and `add_on_change` methods should belong to `Settings`:

```
class Settings:
  def __init__(self):
    self.settings = sublime.load_settings(__name__ + '.sublime-settings')
    self.settings.add_on_change(__name__ + '-reload', self.setup)
    self.setup()

  def setup():
    self.setting1 = self.settings.get('setting1', 'default1')
    self.setting2 = self.settings.get('setting2', 'default2')
    ...

# Global Scope

settings = Settings()
```

Now `Settings` class encapsulates all functionality.
But do we really need instances of this class ?
I don't think so.
That's why `static` should be used:

```
class Settings:
  settings = sublime.load_settings(__name__ + '.sublime-settings')

  @staticmethod
  def init():
    Settings.settings.add_on_change(__name__ + '-reload', Settings.setup)
    Settings.setup()

  @staticmethod
  def setup():
    Settings.setting1 = Settings.settings.get('setting1', 'default1')
    Settings.setting2 = Settings.settings.get('setting2', 'default2')
    ...

# Global Scope

Settings.init()
```

The advantages (if any) of the example above are:

- class encapsulates *all* functionality related to settings
- no need to create instances to access settings

Are there any other "decent" ways to organize Settings ?

Comment: Your argumentation makes absolutely sense. I don’t think there is really a standard way to solve this though, so as long as it works, do what you think is the best way.

Comment: Classes are just instances of their metaclass, so `Settings` _is_ and instance of something. By making everything static you're basically creating a singleton, which is a controversial design -- look it up. By doing so you're also preventing or a least hindering code reuse.

Comment: @martineau, note that i am not trying to make every class static ("everything static"). The reason for Settings class to be static is that plugin doesn't really need multiple instances of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is the best approach, everything encapsulated in a class. The `@staticmethod` approach has no advantages that I can think of - there is nothing at all wrong with having a class which will only ever have one instance created at a time.

The global `settings = Settings()` assignment should be called from inside `plugin_loaded()` to ensure that the ST API is ready, otherwise `sublime.load_settings(FILENAME)` could fail.

Callbacks should be used so that if the user changes a setting Sublime Text does not need to be restarted for the setting's value to be updated. These should be removed in `plugin_unloaded()` in case the user uninstalls the plugin.

Here's a rough template taken from one of my plugins. It should serve as a good starting position from which settings handling can be added to Sublime Text plugins.

Code also in this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mattst/90bf57a9e69b5a02bf604831e3693d66).

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

# The global scope ensures that the settings can
# be easily accessed from within all the classes.
global settings

def plugin_loaded():
    """ 
    This module level function is called on ST startup when the API is ready. 
    """

    global settings
    settings = Settings()
    settings.load_all()

def plugin_unloaded():
    """
    This module level function is called just before the plugin is unloaded.
    """

    settings.remove_callbacks()

class Settings:
    """
    Handles all the settings. A callback method is added for each setting, it 
    gets called by ST if that setting is changed in the settings file.
    """

    def __init__(self):

        FILENAME = "YourPluginName.sublime-settings"
        self.settings = sublime.load_settings(FILENAME)

        # User configurable settings.
        self.max_display_length = None
        self.monospace_font     = None
        self.ellipsis_symbols   = None
        self.prefix_custom      = None
        self.command_names      = None
        # ...

    def load_all(self):
        self.init_setting("max_display_length", self.set_max_display_length)
        self.init_setting("monospace_font", self.set_monospace_font)
        self.init_setting("ellipsis_symbols", self.set_ellipsis_symbols)
        self.init_setting("prefix_custom", self.set_prefix_custom)
        self.init_setting("command_names", self.set_command_names)
        # ...

    def init_setting(self, setting_name, setting_method):
        """
        Calls the setting_method to set the setting's value and registers the 
        setting_method as a callback so that it will be called by ST if the 
        setting's value is changed by the user.
        """

        setting_method()
        self.settings.add_on_change(setting_name, setting_method)

    def remove_callbacks(self):
        self.settings.clear_on_change("max_display_length")
        self.settings.clear_on_change("monospace_font")
        self.settings.clear_on_change("ellipsis_symbols")
        self.settings.clear_on_change("prefix_custom")
        self.settings.clear_on_change("command_names")
        # ...

    # Methods for the user configurable settings.

    def set_max_display_length(self):
        DEFAULT = 70
        MIN_LENGTH = 50
        value = self.integer_setting("max_display_length", DEFAULT, MIN_LENGTH)
        self.max_display_length = value

    def set_monospace_font(self):
        DEFAULT = True
        value = self.boolean_setting("monospace_font", DEFAULT)
        self.monospace_font = value

    def set_ellipsis_symbols(self):
        DEFAULT = "…"
        value = self.string_setting("ellipsis_symbols", DEFAULT)
        self.ellipsis_symbols = value

    def set_prefix_custom(self):
        DEFAULT = ""
        # This setting may be set to a string or a list of strings;
        # if it is a list then ensure all list elements are strings.
        value = self.list_or_string_setting("prefix_custom", DEFAULT)
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for index, item in enumerate(value):
                if not isinstance(item, str):
                    value[index] = str(item)
        self.prefix_custom = value

    def set_command_names(self):
        DEFAULT = []
        value = self.list_setting("command_names", DEFAULT)
        self.command_names = value

    # Methods for settings retrieval; all will return a
    # setting of the required type or the default value.

    def string_setting(self, setting, default):
        return self.setting_of_type(setting, default, str)

    def list_setting(self, setting, default):
        return self.setting_of_type(setting, default, list)

    def boolean_setting(self, setting, default):
        return self.setting_of_type(setting, default, bool)

    def list_or_string_setting(self, setting, default):
        return self.setting_of_type(setting, default, (str, list))

    def setting_of_type(self, setting, default, required_type):
        value = self.settings.get(setting, None)
        return value if isinstance(value, required_type) else default

    # Special case.

    def integer_setting(self, setting, default, min_value):
        value = self.settings.get(setting, None)
        return value if self.is_integer(value) and value >= min_value else default

    def is_integer(self, value):
        # Bool is a subclass of int; isinstance(False, int) == True.
        return isinstance(value, int) and not isinstance(value, bool)
```

Answer (score -2):

Put your plugin settings in a file named `Preferences.sublime-settings` in the root of your package. These settings will be autoloaded by Sublime Text and merged into Sublime's default settings. You can then access all your plugin settings via Sublime APIs without the need for any boilerplate code.

Consider the following plugin settings file named `Preferences.sublime-settings`:

```
{
    "plugin_name_setting1": true,
    "plugin_name_setting2": true
}
```

The settings are available via view objects:

```
window = sublime.active_window()
view = window.active_view()
settings = view.settings()
setting1 = settings.get('plugin_name_setting1')
setting2 = settings.get('plugin_name_setting2')
```

For example, from inside a TextCommand:

```
class ATextCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        setting1 = self.view.settings().get('plugin_name_setting1')
        setting2 = self.view.settings().get('plugin_name_setting2')
```

or from a view object dependency passed into a function:

```
def my_plugin_func(view):
    setting1 = view.settings().get('plugin_name_setting1')
    setting2 = view.settings().get('plugin_name_setting2')
```

You can also access them by loading the preferences file directly:

```
settings = sublime.load_settings('Preferences.sublime-settings')
setting1 = settings.get('plugin_name_setting1')
setting2 = settings.get('plugin_name_setting2')
```

### Pros

The main upside is that there is no boilerplate code needed. You simply create your settings file and drop it into the root folder of your plugin.

The user can configure your plugin globally **and** on a per-project basis.

To set settings globally the user can use the global preferences file, **Menu > Preferences > Settings**:

```
{
    "plugin_name_setting1": true,
    "plugin_name_setting2": true
}
```

To set them at a pre-project level they can use their project file settings, **Menu > Project > Edit Project**:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "plugin_name_setting1": true,
        "plugin_name_setting2": true
    }
}
```

The settings can be used in keymap context constraints too:

```
{ 
    "keys": [",", "a"], 
    "command": "a_plugin_command", 
    "context": [{ "key": "setting.plugin_name_setting2" } ] 
}
```

### Cons

Your user plugin settings are not in a separate named settings file. I don't think this is a big deal if you prefix all your plugin settings with your plugin name, that way they'll be sorted alongside one another in the preference file. I don't know what the other cons are.